# Marquee tag in Jquery

Tags: jquery

hi I want to implement marquee tag in my web from using jquery. in my web from i have text box ,button and div for display the marquee.my requirement is i want to display the textbox text to marquee as sliding after click on button this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btn_click").click(function () {
            var textboxvalue = $("#txtbx_data").val();
            var dis = $("#div_scroll").find(".ticker").text(textboxvalue);
            $('.ticker').each(function () {

            var marq = $('<marquee></marquee>').attr({
                'behavior': 'slide',
                'scrollamount': 08,
                'direction': 'left',
                'width': '100%'
            })
                    $(this).wrap(marq);

            })
        })
    });          


</script>
```

Comment: And your question/problem is what?

Comment: in that every time a marquee is created at runtime and space of marquee is decrsing

Comment: wat is fiddle am new to jquery

Comment: isn't <marquee> deprecated? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ @roXon yup

Comment: I want the text box value as scrolling on my webfrom like news scroll

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547797/very-simple-very-smooth-javascript-marquee

Answer (score 0):

here's a jsfiddle that works, only had to make a few adjustments... http://jsfiddle.net/aM78J/1/

and here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn_click").click(function () {
        $('marquee').remove();
        var textboxvalue = $("#txtbx_data").val();
        $("#div_scroll").find('.ticker').append(
            $('<marquee/>').html(textboxvalue).attr({
                'behavior': 'scroll',
                'scrollamount': 08,
                'direction': 'left',
                'width':'100%'
            })
        );
    }); 
});​
```

but, like mentioned already, marquee is deprecated...