# Marquee : element vs. javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering what is the advantages and disadvantages to use HTML  tag as opposed to achieving the same scrolling text effect using Javascript?

Is the use of `<marquee>` HTML tag encouraged?

Comment: marquee, my oh my oh my http://divshot.github.io/geo-bootstrap/

Comment: I, for one, welcome our underconstruction.gif animated overlords.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You ask

> Is the use of `<marquee>` HTML tag encouraged?

[The w3.org answers](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee) :

> No, really. don't use it.

You have no guarantee of `marquee` element support across future browsers and even when it's present, some of its options might be absent in today's browsers (for example I tested [MDN's examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee#Examples) in Chrome and I got a different bouncing effect than in Firefox).

Most users would prefer not to see any JavaScript based solution either, but if you really need it (like, your boss asks for it), then a search of "JavaScript marquee" gives many solutions, for example

[Very Simple, Very Smooth, JavaScript Marquee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547797/very-simple-very-smooth-javascript-marquee)

JavaScript based solutions have the advantages of being configurable and of not being based on a non standard element (*"HTML5 classifies it as a non-conforming feature.")*.

Comment: Isn't the reason that the UX effect is bad, meaning its javascript replacement isn't any better?

Comment: why use a javascript version of marquee tag over the marquee, the point is not to use it at all, isn't it.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'd say that the most important for the w3.org isn't that the UX effect is bad but that it's very specific, that is the w3.org can't design all tuning and parameterization desirable features for such a rarely used effect.

Comment: heretic! `marquee` is the best element html was supposed to have, same as `blink`!!!

Comment: @Christoph `<marquee><blink><big><big><big><font color=red bg-color=yellow>`

Comment: @JanDvorak Agree. The Client wants it, and I have no say. I wouldn't want it if it was for my own website - its definitely ugly. I was juggling whether to use the existing element or use Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

- Marquee is Microsoft 1990's technology
- Marquee was/is/will never be a w3c standard
- Marquee is very ugly,

but

ALL browsers support it (even IOS safari!)

then

if you are sure you want this very ugly think on your website, use it.

eventual future non supporting browsers simply fallback to simple static style.

Comment: but you can't be sure about the support. Every vendor could decide to drop the support in the next version...

Comment: Try the MDN examples in Firefox and Chrome. You'll notice they behave differently.