# Detect the number of iteration count of animation that the marquee tag completes

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to count the number of iterations that the marquee tag completes?

Particularly, I want to generate specific action at the *nth* number of animation count. I found the `onbounce` and `onFinish` events but those are not working across different browsers.

Comment: Please... Just don't use the `<marquee>` tag. If you really need that functionality, use or write a script to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

The `<marquee>` tag (like `<blink>`) is not standard HTML and is not supported very well across browsers. Your best option is to use javascript to implement the functionality.

Rather than repeat the code already mentioned, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547797/very-simple-very-smooth-javascript-marquee) the answers to which offer an alternate implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the link from that..http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin