# jQuery-Marquee only working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, marquee

I'm using [jQuery-Marquee](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee) to simulate a marquee effect for a 'latest tweet' div. But it only works in Firefox. It outputs correctly in Chrome but the marquee doesn't scroll for some reason. Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

HTML (this is what outputs)

```
<div class="latest-tweets">
  <ul class="sf-js-enabled">
    <li>
      <p class="tweet-text">
        <div style="width: 100000px; margin-left: 0px;" class="js-marquee-wrapper">
          <div class="js-marquee" style="margin-right: 0px; float: left;">RT <a class="twitter-screen-name" href="https://twitter.com/Kollaboration" target="_blank">@Kollaboration</a>: Angry Asian American, a new show from <a class="twitter-screen-name" href="https://twitter.com/angryasianman" target="_blank">@angryasianman</a> <a class="twitter-screen-name" href="https://twitter.com/jennyyangtv" target="_blank">@jennyyangtv</a> on <a class="twitter-screen-name" href="https://twitter.com/ISATVofficial" target="_blank">@ISATVofficial</a> Watch the first angry ep. here: http…<a href="http://twitter.com/ISATVofficial/status/447119023319162881" target="_blank">- 1 day ago</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript (in the footer of the actual site)

```
<script src="jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.tweet-text').marquee({
      pauseOnHover: true,
      duration: 8000
    });
  });
</script>
```

CSS

```
.latest-tweets {
  color: #ddd;
  float: left;
  line-height: 42px;
}
.latest-tweets ul {
  height: 42px;
  max-width: 550px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
}
.latest-tweets li {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 42px;
}
.latest-tweets p {
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tweet-text {
  width: 550px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tweet-details {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.tweet-details a {
  text-transform: none !important;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, there are no keyframes rules added for webkit, only moz-marquee animation is set, so your script does not add the required CSS rules. Did you try to separate the script from page context and checked if you still have the same problem?

Comment: @axel.michel The separated script works fine as displayed here: http://jsfiddle.net/jc7F3/189/ However, I have the same setup on my own site but the marquee isn't scrolling. But it's strange that it works in Firefox. Also, I have tried disabling all of my plugins on WordPress as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not able to apply the `marquee` plugin you're using to elements that are `display: inline;`.

Try removing the `display: inline;` on the `<p class="tweet-text">` element or changing it to `display: block;`. You may have to adjust some other CSS to account for this caveat, but that should fix it.

Comment: I appreciate you taking a look. I'm doing some testing for another plugin so the theme is reverted back to the default but I will try this in a minute.

Comment: No problem.  For future reference, I think it's SA best practice to emulate your problem at a static location such as jsFiddle instead of posting a link to the problem where it will eventually no longer be active.  Just in case someone with a similar problem stumbles across this answer.  Hope you get it working!

Comment: That did it. I changed it to `display:inline-block` and it's scrolling fine now. Thanks for the help and I'll remember to emulate my problem at a static location from now on.

Comment: Glad you got it working! And no worries -- I've just seen questions locked for that reason and didn't want you to run into that issue.

Comment: For me, my container was already `display:block`. It also needed `overflow: hidden`.