# Auto-scrolling specific gridview cell on webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, cells, autoscroll

I was wondering if it was possible to auto-scroll a specific column of cells (left to right) in a gridview in asp.net/c#.

I have a gridview filled from a database, and there's a column that can have certain cells anywhere from 1 character up to 100 characters. all other columns are pretty close in length (varying only 2-3 characters maximum). For this column right now, i have it doing this

```
        <ItemTemplate>
           <div style ="overflow: auto;">
           <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[QA Msg]") %>' Width="100"></asp:Label>
           </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

Which is fine if somebody wants to view it themselves, but this is up on a display and both the database and this page are updated automatically, so automatically scrolling text in this column would be the best solution that I can think of. If anybody knows how I could do this, or has another solution (wrapping pushes some of the lower rows off the screen so that doesn't work) it would be appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT: clarifying my question, Currently these gridview cells down this column have scroll-bars to manually scroll if necessary. I am looking for a way to make the text scroll through automatically on a loop (possibly with javascript?)

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547797/very-simple-very-smooth-javascript-marquee

Answer (score 0):

Here, I made example using `css` and `js`

css

```
.divCC 
{
   width:100px; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;
}
.divCnt
{
  width: 100px; white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  animation:marquee 5s linear; /*infinite*/
}
@keyframes marquee 
{
  0%   { text-indent: 0px }
  100% { text-indent: -100px }
}
```

js :

```
function animDiv() {
            var pp = document.getElementById('gvQAMsg').getElementsByTagName('div');
            if (pp != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < pp.length; i++) {
                    if (pp[i].className == 'divCC') {
                        var rr = pp[i].getElementsByTagName('span');
                        if (rr[0].offsetWidth > pp[i].clientWidth) {
                            pp[i].className = 'divCnt';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

html :

```
<body onload="animDiv();">
<asp:GridView ID="gvQAMsg" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True" DataSourceID="*your_SqlDataSource*" > 
     <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QA Msg" SortExpression="[QA Msg]">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="divCC">
          <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[QA Msg]")%>'></asp:Label>
          </div>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</body>
```

I just don't know how to achieve this without `js`.

So, `onload` start `animDiv` function. Function search all `divs` inside `GridView`, check is `className="divCC"` of div. If it is, then compare `div` and `span` `widths`. If `span` is wider than `div` `className` is replaced for `divCnt` which have animation.

You'll see in `css` for `animation` You can add `infinite` and animation will never stop. This example is with autoscroll text which is wider then `div` container only once.

This is not so clean code, but...

I hope so this is what You need.

**Update : [jsfiddle simulation](https://jsfiddle.net/krtrqxb8/)**

Comment: The problem with this if I'm understanding it is that it would animate every cell larger than a certain size in the whole gridview would it not? I need it to animate on cells in the "QA Msg" column. Is there some way to only make it animate that single column?

Comment: @user3361936 Yes, use this `divCC` class only for `QA Msg` column. `js` will check and animate `span/label` only which is child of `div` with `divCC` class. Every else `div` (who doesn't have `divCC` class) will not be proceeded. For other columns, which don't need animation, place some else `class` **but not** `divCC`.