# What is the equivalent of <marquee> tag in HTML5?

Tags: html

In HTML 4, there is this `<marquee>` tag that shows sliding text across the screen.
What is its equivalent in HTML5?

Comment: None, as far as I know.

Comment: try to use css animation 

Comment: It has been deprecated. You'll probably have to use javascript, implementing it with a jQuery UI effect should be straightforward. Check out this demo, I think this is what you are after: http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

Comment: Related: [What is `<marquee>` and what can i do with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454580/html-what-is-marquee-and-what-can-i-do-with-it). Also: [Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/#search=marquee).

Comment: There is no `<marquee>` tag in **any** HTML specification, ever, *excepting* HTML5 which only places it there for the sole purpose of making it obsolete so browser vendors can warn you it will be removed. @HarshShah you can't deprecate something in the spec that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By css animation you can do the same thing

```css
.holder {
  background:#ccc;
  padding:0.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.news {
  animation : slide 10s linear infinite;
  
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translatex(0%)
  }

  100% {
    transform: translatex(100%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="news">Hello....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is a good alternative in my own example, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The marquee-tag is not and never has been an HTML standard. You can create the behaviour with JS/CSS by your own.

Alternatively, there are libraries around which you can use. One option would be the library called [SuperMarquee](https://superplug.in/supermarquee) which also offers a WebComponent version. This really comes close to using the marquee-tag itself. Just use "super-marquee"-tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such alternative. The behavior provided by `<marquee>` can be achieved using css/js though.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using browser vendor specific CSS and CSS3 specifications.

Here is an example:

```
{
  width: 200px; height: 50px; white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x:-webkit-marquee;
  -webkit-marquee-direction: forwards;
  -webkit-marquee-style: scroll;
  -webkit-marquee-speed: normal;
  -webkit-marquee-increment: small;
  -webkit-marquee-repetition: 5;
  overflow-x: marquee-line;
  marquee-direction: forward;
  marquee-style: scroll;
  marquee-speed: normal;
  marquee-play-count: 5;
}
```

Check out [this](https://www.lifewire.com/scrollable-content-html5-css3-without-marquee-3467007) post for explanation of each property

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in Firefox, Chrome or Edge. I'm sure CSS has become powerful enough to achieve something like this but you possibly need to use transitions rather than these proprietary properties.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  it actually did used to be true for a brief moment in time but the marquee module was dropped from the CSS3 specification by the W3C. W3C also suggested transitions instead. Personally I think we should have kept it just for posterity but thats me