# How to make text infinite loop with controll

Tags: javascript, css, slider, infinite-loop

I try to make an infinite text loop like [that](https://codepen.io/helleholmsen/pen/LBYzzz).
It will be added on a cordova app so I want to make a pure css/js without any plugin.

The text loop can be stopped when :active and user can move the loop with the finger.

I can't find a good example online. Maybe I'm not looking for the good keyword?
I'm searching for "infinite text loop" "text slider"

```
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <span class="number">26</span>
    <p>comments</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="number">3.86</span>
    <p>Comment per post</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="number">15</span>
    <p>Like per video</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm

Comment: @JoseRojas not working inside ionic but thanks I'm looking for marquee now

Comment: You might wanna look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547797/very-simple-very-smooth-javascript-marquee